# How to position a FrameAnimation in android?

Tags: android, graphics

I have a image loaded as a background and when the screen is touched I want to animate that portion of the screen with a frameanimation. My frameanimation consists of 9 different png files which are made from just the portion of the screen I want animated. I can get it working when I use entire backgrounds as the frames for the animations, but when I use setbounds() to tell the frameanimation where to draw, I end up with the frameanimation being scaled up to fill the entire screen, which also erase my background. How can I get the frameanimation to stay it's original size and locate it at the same time? I can post  code later if this isn't clear, i'm not at the comp right now

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)
{
   switch (event.getAction())
   {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         this.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.nova);
         Object bg = this.getBackground
         touchAni.setBounds (152, 156, 152+140, 156+140);

         touchAni = (AnimationDrawable) bg;

         if (!touchAni.isRunning())
            touchAni.start ();
         else
         {
            touchAni.stop();
            touchAni.start();
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after much puttering around, I finally found the BounceActivity code here: http://rsequence.com/android_blog/node/107.  Seems really complicated for such a simple task but gets me what I want.

Of note, if anyone else finds it useful, the Handler() codes needs to have a switch in it so it's not spinning off cpu cycles to BounceView.draw() when nothing is happening on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have resolved a similar problem is that I added another image component to my layout xml on top of the component I want to animate. Normally that image component is `android:visibility="gone"`
but when I want to run the frame animation I set it visible and start the animation.

This way you can place the animation component wherever you want in your layout.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I've added code to my original question.  What is happening, is the first time the screen is touched, the R.drawable.nova animation-list (xml file describing the animation) is scaled to fit the entire screen, and then the animation plays.  Subsequent touches on the screen draw the nova animation in the correct position, however the background is not what I intended (overwritten by the nova animation being scaled-up).  Where would I add the image component exactly?  In the animation-list xml file, or somewhere in the onTouchEvent() method?